# For good style, should I define inner classes before methods or vice versa in Python?

Tags: python, coding-style, inner-classes

I read [PEP 8: Style Guide for Python code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), but I couldn't find anything on what order I should define inner classes or methods in a class.

For example, should I do

```
class CustomClass(BaseClass):
    class Meta:
        foo = self.bar

    def foo_bar(self):
        return False

    bar = 1
```

or

```
class CustomClass(BaseClass):
    def foo_bar(self):
        return False

    class Meta:
        foo = self.bar

    bar = 1
```

?

**EDIT:** Here is a Django source code. They actually define `fields`, then `inner classes`, then `methods`:

```
class LogEntry(models.Model):
    action_time = models.DateTimeField(_('action time'), auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, blank=True, null=True)
    object_id = models.TextField(_('object id'), blank=True, null=True)
    object_repr = models.CharField(_('object repr'), max_length=200)
    action_flag = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('action flag'))
    change_message = models.TextField(_('change message'), blank=True)

    objects = LogEntryManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('log entry')
        verbose_name_plural = _('log entries')
        db_table = 'django_admin_log'
        ordering = ('-action_time',)

    def __repr__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.action_time)

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.action_flag == ADDITION:
            return _('Added "%(object)s".') % {'object': self.object_repr}
        elif self.action_flag == CHANGE:
            return _('Changed "%(object)s" - %(changes)s') % {'object': self.object_repr, 'changes': self.change_message}
        elif self.action_flag == DELETION:
            return _('Deleted "%(object)s."') % {'object': self.object_repr}

        return _('LogEntry Object')

    def is_addition(self):
        return self.action_flag == ADDITION

    def is_change(self):
        return self.action_flag == CHANGE

    def is_deletion(self):
        return self.action_flag == DELETION

    def get_edited_object(self):
        "Returns the edited object represented by this log entry"
        return self.content_type.get_object_for_this_type(pk=self.object_id)

    def get_admin_url(self):
        """
        Returns the admin URL to edit the object represented by this log entry.
        This is relative to the Django admin index page.
        """
        if self.content_type and self.object_id:
            return mark_safe(u"%s/%s/%s/" % (self.content_type.app_label, self.content_type.model, quote(self.object_id)))
        return None
```

Comment: I think you mean inner classes. Subclasses are something completely different.

Comment: @jpm: Absolutely. I've made some edits to reflect this.

Comment: I can't remember ever having seen a nested class in a Python program. I'd just go with whatever Django does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The generally accepted practice is to define fields, then inner classes, then methods.

Comment: Why is there a preference towards this?

Comment: @Paul: Honestly, I couldn't tell you. It just seems to be what everyone does.

Comment: I would note that inner classes don't serve too much purpose in Python. As there is no such thing as 'private' in python and modules serve to give most of the structural control you need.

Comment: In Python per se, no. But frameworks (e.g. Django) use them for various things.

Comment: Ya, I actually saw what @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams said in the Django source code, but I wanted to see what Python programmers would say about it.

Comment: @Lattyware It's more useful to think of them as "member classes" rather than "inner classes", because they are entirely equivalent to setting a variable that holds a class (and they can't access their outer class).

Comment: Actually looking at the Django source code, I notice it's `fields`, then `inner classes`, then `methods`. I'll post an example in my question.